# Python Multiprocessing manager prunes some methods

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, magic-methods

I've found that `Manager` rarely works in practice with most of the custom objects as it removes some class members. See an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
cs_pure = CubicSpline([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
test_pure = cs_pure(1)
m = Manager()
m.register('CubicSpline', CubicSpline)
cs_m = m.CubicSpline([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
test_m = cs_m(1)
```

This will raise an exception:

```
TypeError: 'AutoProxy[CubicSpline]' object is not callable
```

Surprisingly, most of other methods (such as `integrate`, `differentiate`) work as expected. The `__call__` method is non-existent, though.

Is there are a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `test_m = cs_m(1)`?

First of all from my experience you have to register a managed class with the manager's class before the manager server is started:

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
from multiprocessing import Manager
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

SyncManager.register('CubicSpline', CubicSpline)
m = Manager()
...
```

So I am not sure how you got as far as you did. It also more usual to create your own manager class if you do not need all the other registered managed classes that are implemented with the `SyncManager` (e.g. `dict`). I will demonstrate that in the following code (use this technique or not as you wish).

I believe the problem is that the `__call__` method is not automatically being generated in the proxy class that is generated for you when you do not define your own proxy class. Rather than defining your own proxy class, I think the simpler solution is to subclass the `CubicSpline` class and add an additional method such as `evaluate_polynomial` that will simply call the superclass `__call__` method:

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

class CubicSplineManager(BaseManager):
    pass

class MyCubicSpline(CubicSpline):
    def evaluate_polynomial(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cs_pure = CubicSpline([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
    test_pure = cs_pure(1)
    print(test_pure)
    CubicSplineManager.register('CubicSpline', MyCubicSpline)
    m = CubicSplineManager()
    m.start() # We must explicitly start the server
    cs_m = m.CubicSpline([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
    test_m = cs_m.evaluate_polynomial(1)
    print(test_m)
```

Prints:

```
1.0
1.0
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to budge however, I am unable to resolve this issue that you had helped earlier with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703252/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-in-if-else-when-condition-matches) Can you please help?

Comment: @PyNoob Your link goes to a question that you did not post and has an accepted answer. So what do you need help with?

Comment: You are correct. One for the solutions is an accepted answer and resolved the question. I apologize for the attention.